# How to diplay all elements with one request in javascript with mailchimp API

Tags: javascript, node.js, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3

I'm calling the API mailchimp to get à list of members and I display all email address of my members by using this code:

```
client = require("@mailchimp/mailchimp_marketing");


client.setConfig({
apiKey: "MY API KEY",
server: "MY SERVER",
});


const run = async () => {
  const response = await client.lists.getListMembersInfo("LIST ID");
  for (element of response.members){
    arrayObject = Object.values(element);
    console.log(arrayObject[1]);
 };
};

run();
```

"MY API KEY", "MY SERVER" and "LIST ID" are fake, I have the real one in my code.

My problem is that only the 10 first email address are display but I have 1058 email address in total.
I can make 105 other request to get the 1058 total email address but I don't know how to do it. I also don't know how to change the `count` parameter because I don't use a URL to call my API.

So, how can I display all items in my terminal ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go through the [git repository](https://github.com/mailchimp/mailchimp-marketing-node/blob/14d7a6cdcfda5da32f420d9fee7d7915769a818d/src/api/ListsApi.js#L1577) you can see that the `getListMembersInfo` method takes a second parameter where you can specify the `count`

```
const response = await client.lists.getListMembersInfo("LIST ID", { count: 100 });
```